Allow editing already-submitted “In need of moderator intervention” flag comments
After I submit text for the flagging reason “In need of moderator intervention”, it's not possible to edit it.



So my feature-request is: after submitting the "In need of moderator intervention" flag, allow me to edit my text for that flagging reason any number of times before the flag is reviewed by a moderator.
I can edit my spelling mistakes, and add more information for that flagged question.

This is just like suggesting edits. I can make changes to my suggested edit any number of times before it gets reviewed. E.g. I can correct a typo error that I introduced.

Allowing users to edit "in need of moderator intervention" and "Something else" flags would create timing problems and require coordination between that interface and the moderator flag dashboard, along with the display in the question page and the multiple lists of flags, so the moderators always see the most recent version. It's much easier to just do what's currently done, which is allowing you to retract the flag and raise a new one with the changed text.

In cases like this, you can just retract the flag and cast a new one with the updated reason. What you propose is slightly faster, but it doesn't come up that often (flagging reasons don't need to be optimized for grammar or formatting, only for clarity or additional information), so I'd rather have the development team spend time on things that add more value.
